# Does this integral inequality hold true?

Tags: calculus

If $f(x)$ is a monotonically decreasing, continuous function then:
$$\sum_{x=a}^{b} f(x) \geq \int_{a}^{b+1}f(x)dx.$$
If yes, then how can I prove it?

Comment: Divide $[a,b]$ into $b-a$ intervals of legth $1$. For every interval $[n,n+1]$ you have $$f(n) = \int_n^{n+1} f(n) dx \ge \int_n^{n+1}f(x)dx$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Note that $f(c)\geq f(x)$ for all $x\in [c,c+1]$ implies that
$$f(c)=\int_{c}^{c+1}f(c)dx \geq  \int_{c}^{c+1}f(x) dx.$$